# Pivot table Programming in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data Excel sheet in the below format:

```
Name   Fruits    Condition of Fruits
=====  ======    ====================

Ram    Apple       Good

Jadu   Apple       Bad

Tina   Orange      Good

Ram    Orange      Good

Tina   Apple       Bad

Ram    Apple       Bad
```

Output of the Pivot program in the other sheet of the same excel, say in sheet(2) should be 
like this:

```
Name  Fruits   Condition of Fruits
====  ======   ===================
               Good       Bad    Total
               ====      =====  ======
Ram   Apple     1           1     2
Ram   Orange    1           0     1
Tina  Apple     0           1     1
Tina  Orange    1           0     1
jadu  Apple     0           1     1
===================================
Grand Total     3           3     6
===================================
```

The above format needs to be present in the Excel in the sheet(2), whenever sheet(1) will be having source data within it as shown in the first table.

I want Macro program to create using Excel pivot table concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert a pivot table on your data, drag these columns into the Row Labels:

- Name
- Fruit.

Then drag this column into the Column Labels:

- Condition of Fruit.

Drag the same column into Values:

- Condition of Fruit.

The pivot table looks almost the same as yours (except the fruit comes under the name, instead of repeating the name for each fruit).

[image: Screen shot pivot table]

Whenever you update the data in sheet 1, you may have the pivot table reflect this by right-clicking on the table and choosing Refresh.

Comment: may i know,how to do pivot table refresh automatically using vbscript?

Comment: Sure, do a search for "VBA automatic refresh pivot table"; the top several hits had the right answer, for example, http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/refresh_pt.php.

Comment: Here in this post i have seen some excel sheet pivot table formation screenshot provided by you. Did you delete that?

Comment: No, I didn't delete the screen shot. Please try to reload this page. If that fails, you may find the screenshot at http://i.stack.imgur.com/qjMnB.png.

Comment: Hi rajah, i searched but couldn't find out any pivot table automation idea,what i was looking for.Could you give me an idea for the same?

Comment: I got lots of results search for "VBA automatic refresh pivot table." http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=80 gives a simple, easy-to-follow solution. If you can't get it working, post another question and tell us what you tried.

Comment: okay!I will do,but if i get my answer from here,it would be better for me :-)

Comment: May i have some idea from you on the below post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878356/how-to-get-pack-all-the-nonnull-data-from-a-row-of-null-and-non-null-data-into-a