# Column nullification using Vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Please follow the table where some tasks details have been gathered.Now i am looking for any VBscript on these types of excel sheet which can check all the TCompdate column,If it is found there is no value in that column then its related two columns say here T,TSdate should be blank.

***Input Table***

```
 PID     T1     T1Sdate   T1Compdate   T2      T2Sdate     T2Compdate   T3    T3Sdate   T3Compdate

 10      A     2/5/11      4/5/11      B      06/09/12                  C     11/11/11
 11      A     2/5/11                  B      06/09/12     8/8/10       C     11/11/11   5/4/11
 12      A     2/5/11                  B      06/09/12     8/8/10       C     11/11/11   5/4/11
```

***Output Table***

```
 PID     T1     T1Sdate   T1Compdate   T2      T2Sdate     T2Compdate   T3    T3Sdate   T3Compdate

 10      A     2/5/11      4/5/11                        
 11                                    B      06/09/12     8/8/10       C     11/11/11   5/4/11
 12                                    B      06/09/12     8/8/10       C     11/11/11   5/4/11
```

***CODE:***

```
   Option Explicit

  Dim objExcel1,objWorkbook
  Dim strPathExcel1
  Dim objSheet1,IntRow1
  Dim Counter

   Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\TestVBSScripts\DataNullification\DataNullification.xlsx"

   Set objWorkbook=objExcel1.Workbooks.open(strPathExcel1)
   Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

IntRow1=2
Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1).Value <> ""

For Counter=2 to 13 Step 3

 If objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,Counter+2).Value = "" Then

 objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,Counter).Value=""
 objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,Counter+1).Value=""

 End If

Next


 IntRow1=IntRow1+1
 Loop

  '=======================
 objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPathExcel1
 objExcel1.Workbooks.close
 objExcel1.Application.Quit
 '======================
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which *specific* part of the task are you having problems with? You should include any code you have so far in your question.

Comment: I used a conventional loop to iterate through the rows and then check each value of the specified column if it Nulls or not.So it is time cosuming. So i wish to have some more faster check and nullifying its pre- 2 columns without checking what values they are containing.But i think if it could be done column wise, or something like that. That's why i posted here the idea.

Comment: You should still include your existing code.

Comment: But the code i have deleted,it was too slow to run.And post the concern here.I told you just before that i was doing the job row by row.with 3000+ rows in my actual sheet and 320 columns mada the code so annoyed that i delted it.

Comment: Hi Tim, I just pasted my one.But I need it more advanced way which can take as much less time as possible. Please help me here.

Comment: That looks OK to me - how long does it take, and how much faster do you need it to be?  Are there any formulas on the sheet?  One thing to try is to turn off ScreenUpdating and set Calculation to Manual before you start your loop.

Comment: Can you edit my code where you want to put those statements,please do write there in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:??

EDIT: ADD MY SAMPLE INPUT & OUTPUT RESULT

EDIT: Variable added, ChuckSize

EDIT: also change the lane `startCol = objSheet1.Range("A1").column`
The "A" to "S", to whatever column your PID is at,
assumption made: Your data starts from row 1

A solution using @Tim's Solution + the 2D Array optimization tech.

**Sample Input**:

```
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   PID T1Name  T1StartDate T1FinishDate    Total Time Spent    T2Name  T2StartDate T2FinishDate    Total Time Spent    T3Name  T3StartDate T3FinishDate    Total Time Spent
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   11  S1  12/7/2012   19/7/2012   100                         19/7/2012   
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   12  S1  12/7/2012                           S2      19/7/2012   
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   13  12/7/2012                   11/5/2012           S6      12/5/2010
```

**Sample Output**:

```
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   PID T1Name  T1StartDate T1FinishDate    Total Time Spent    T2Name  T2StartDate T2FinishDate    Total Time Spent    T3Name  T3StartDate T3FinishDate    Total Time Spent
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   11  S1  12/7/2012   19/7/2012   100                             
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   12                                              
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   13
```

Code:

```
 Option Explicit

  Dim objExcel1,objWorkbook
  Dim strPathExcel1
  Dim objSheet1,IntRow1
  Dim Counter
  dim height
  dim i 
  dim dataArray
  dim startCol 
  dim j 
  dim chuckSize 
   Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   strPathExcel1 = "C:\Users\wangCL\Desktop\data.xlsx"

   Set objWorkbook=objExcel1.Workbooks.open(strPathExcel1)
   Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data (4)")

   objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = False
   objExcel1.Calculation = -4135  'xlCalculationManual
   startCol = objSheet1.Range("K1").column 'column with PID is 
   chuckSize = 4
   Height = objSheet1.Cells(objSheet1.Rows.Count, startCol).End(-4162).Row '-4162 is xlUp
If Height >= 2 Then
    ReDim dataArray(Height - 2, 12) '12 columns in total
    dataArray = objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(2, startCol + 1), objSheet1.Cells(Height, startCol + 12)).Value
    For i = 1 To Height - 1
        For Counter = 1 To 12 Step chuckSize
        If dataArray(i, Counter + chuckSize-1) = "" Then
            For j = 0 to chuckSize - 2
            dataArray(i, Counter + j) = ""
            next 
        End If

        Next
    Next
    'assigning the values back into the worksheet
    objSheet1.Range(objSheet1.Cells(2, startCol + 1), objSheet1.Cells(Height, startCol + 12)).Value =     dataArray
End If

   objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = True
   objExcel1.Calculation = -4105   'xlCalculationAutomatic

  '=======================
 objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Save
 objExcel1.Workbooks.close
 objExcel1.Application.Quit
 '======================
```

Comment: can you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885342/data-partition-in-an-excel-row#comment19133553_13885342

Answer (score 1):

Turning off calculation and screen updating:

```
Option Explicit

  Dim objExcel1,objWorkbook
  Dim strPathExcel1
  Dim objSheet1,IntRow1
  Dim Counter

   Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\TestVBSScripts\DataNullification\DataNullification.xlsx"

   Set objWorkbook=objExcel1.Workbooks.open(strPathExcel1)
   Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

   objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = False
   objExcel1.Calculation = -4135  'xlCalculationManual

IntRow1=2
Do While objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1).Value <> ""

For Counter=2 to 13 Step 3

 If objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,Counter+2).Value = "" Then

 objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,Counter).Value=""
 objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,Counter+1).Value=""

 End If

Next


 IntRow1=IntRow1+1
 Loop

   objExcel1.ScreenUpdating = True
   objExcel1.Calculation = -4105   'xlCalculationAutomatic

  '=======================
 objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPathExcel1
 objExcel1.Workbooks.close
 objExcel1.Application.Quit
 '======================
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.i will use your tips.But i was comparing the Null values in the loop. So i was looking for if anyway i can sarch or check that null values within three columns directly and if i could avoid the "Or" operator,code can be more efficient.So any idea from you on that?

Comment: Try it first. Is it faster? Then answer my questions below your original question.

Comment: Tim, I tried it. That's why i am asking if anyway you could improve this.With 300 columns and 3700 rows,such comparisons and then doing these "Or" checking seems making my code slower..

Comment: there is no formula on the sheet.

Comment: How long does it take, and how fast does it need to be?

Comment: Okie... 3700 rows and 300 columns it is taking nearly 15- 19 mins,,, which is really impacting the overall performance.

Comment: Why are you using VBScript and not VBA? I'm guessing that would be much faster.

Comment: but VBA is not the one i was asked to do,thus i choose VBS.But i am quite sure that if we do kind of engineering on this code,can improve the performance.

Comment: I don't have time to write it, but you can try loading your entire dataset into a 2D array, operating on that array, and then dumping the array back to the sheet in one operation. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: I don't have knowledge on things,you are talking about,if i get your help,would helpful for me

Comment: Still I would like to wait for some magical snippet from you,which can reduce my code performance.I never think myself till now I can write a better code than you.Still you accept so i did,only with the change as you posted in the code of mine. But will wait from you something better than me.

Comment: That's not how it works here. I gave you a suggestion and pointed you to a good overview of how that might be coded. Did you try to see if you could make that work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21149/discussion-between-vbslover-and-tim-williams)

Comment: May I have some idea from you on my below post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742820/pivot-table-programming-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

Why use vba at all - this can be done with formulas. For the first data row in your table the formulas are

`=D1  =IF(ISBLANK(D3),"",B3)  =IF(ISBLANK(D3),"",C3)  =IF(ISBLANK(D3),"",D3)  =IF(ISBLANK(G3),"",E3)` etc

Comment: Hi Dale, Thanks for your suggestions.But I have some VBScripts Through which 10 sheets will be created and the data will be arranged over there.In such one of the sheet,after pulling data in the sheet,i have to do such arrangement.Thus we need to code it as well. Could you please help me here to implement your thought by using VBScript?