# How to get pack all the nonnull data from a row of null and non-null data into an array using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have an excel sheet,which has 144 coulms-(4 columns contains one set).i.e 36 sets i do have. Now how can i take out only the Non-Null data from the 2000X350 Excel sheet matrix data,into an 2D array using VBScript?

Here is an Example sheet:

```
   PID  T1 T1SD T1CD T1ST T2 T2SD T2CD T2ST T3 T3SD T3CD T3ST T4 T4SD T4CD T4ST ........
    10  a   b          b   t             r                     t   k   l     o
    11                     p   p    m    d   n   n    n    b
    .
    .
```

PID on the column number 11 always.Evey set is comprised of (TN,TNSD,TNCD,TNST) where N=1 to 36. Array will not pick up data into it only iff a set full contains NUll data . Once all the data pick up will be done,it should then relase the data to each row. But thing should be remembered that if 2D array should assign data to the row from where it has been picked up.

Data(1,1)=(a,b,,b,t,,,r,t,k,l,o) During pick up
Cell(2,12)=(a,b,,b,t,,,r,t,k,l,o) when releasing the data.

that means data should need to mapped to the correct rows(setwise)

Please let me know if you have any confusion.

***EDIT:***
***Output table***

```
    PID  T1 T1SD T1CD T1ST T2 T2SD T2CD T2ST  T3 T3SD T3CD T3ST T4 T4SD T4CD T4ST
    10  a   b          b   t              r    t   k   l     o
    11  p   p    m     d   n   n    n    b
```

Thanks,Arup

Comment: Can any one please help me in this Question? I was really stuck for this.

Comment: Are you trying to move the b under T1ST to T1CD? And then t under T1ST? And then r under T2? Maybe a before and after would be in order.

Comment: No, here 4 columns made a set. So now i would like to move data from right to left.data movement condition is suppose a 4 set of data can move its left if its left side 4 columns are fully blank,if its left set has a single data,no move will be allowed.This way all the empty set and non-empty set will be partitioned. hope you understand now

Comment: The table above is what you have, right? Can you edit your post and put in a table of what you want?

Comment: I am giving you actualy snaps,where the actual column you can see,here is the one i conceptually posted.

Comment: See my EDIT... where output table i have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer that should get you a nudge in the right direction.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim whichT As Integer
Dim whichC As Integer
Dim allNull As Boolean
Dim contents As String

For whichT = 0 to 8 ' this is which T set
  allNull = True
  for whichC = 1 to 4 ' this is which of the 4 elements
    contents = Cells(2, whichT * 4 + whichC + 1)
    Debug.Print "Contents of col ", whichT * 4 + whichC + 1, "are", contents
    If Len(contents) > 0 then allNull = False  ' any one of the non-blank elements sets to False
  Next whichC
  If allNull Then ... ' do some processing to move over the next 4.
Next whichT
End Sub
```

Comment: But can i have a generic full version code of it,as when i tried for some data it got shifted properly,but most of the tim it was not...

Comment: Arup, give it your best effort at "If allNull Then ..."  If you are still having problems, post what you have and the community will take a look at it. SO doesn't usually answer questions like "Please solve this programming problem for me." We do, however, help if you have made a strong effort and are running into problems.

Comment: but "allNull" flag's significance? means the purpose of it?

Comment: It means that all of set (Tx, TxSD, TxCD, and TxST) are null and ready to be replaced.

Comment: I will try to code your idea,mean while can you see one post,which i found when i was searching stack-overflow search engine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895587/sorting-order-check-using-vbscript

Comment: Did you look into the above link?