# Sorting order check using VBScript

Tags: vba, date, excel, vbscript, sorting

Suppose I have an array arr1 which contains date values as below :

Arr1(50)=("9/3/2012  4:57:02 AM","22/3/2012  5:57:02 AM","9/5/2012  8:57:02 AM","9/3/2011  4:57:02 AM")

***Edit***

```
 Dim CellCount
 Dim Arr(10)

 CellCount=0
 Do Untill arr(CellCount)="" And Ubound(Arr)>9

  If CStr(arr(CellCount) < arr(CellCount+1)) Then

    MsgBox(arr(CellCount)&"is good")

   Else

     MsgBox(arr(CellCount +1)&"is bad")
     Exit Do

   End if

CellCount=CellCount+1
Loop
```

Now, Is there any direct way,without using any Looping technique,to find out if the Arr1() has the date values ascending or not?

Thanks,

Comment: any faster comparison method which can perform the task what i asked? pleasse sugest me!

Comment: Using `Worksheetfunction.Small/Large/Rank/Max/Min` may help to skip some cycles.

Comment: may I get some code demo on that Juri? Please

Comment: @Jüri Ruut Please help me here

Comment: @TukaiRakshit as long as you ask questions in bits and pieces...here and there without providing proper picture, you will have to continue to keep creating logins sigh... :(

Comment: What confusion you have here?  :-) I would like to get a direct way,by which I can test if an array element is in increasing order or not- that is query from me :-)

Comment: @bonCodigo can I have some quick idea here? Please... any good trick if you want to suggest?

Comment: @Jüri Ruut Any good trick would you like to advice me here,please?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit this is not solved by Ekkehard's answer? He gave you the tip. What can we do for you more?

Comment: I didn't get his point! thus asking again here!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit please go through the so called answer I provided. Then let us know if that makes sense to you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is answering your question. You asked, ***is there a way to find if sorted without a loop?*** 
He said no. Your eyes, my eyes can see if it's sorted or not. But how do you expect Excel/computer to do so without going through collections elements?

When data is in an array, you need to loop through its elements. Hope it's clear.

So the best I could say,

- split it by the comma delimiter into a variant if required. But not necessary since Array() can put elements into a 1D variant
- dump it into a `Range` using Transpose
- use Sheet sorting method/function to sort the range as a whole

  ---> so you know it's now sorted.
- then traspose back into a variant array

Some code snippet to get you going on this direction:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub omgArraySort()
       Dim inputArray As Variant
       Dim outputArray As Variant
       Dim upperB as Long

       inputArray = Array("9/3/2012 4:57:02 AM","22/3/2012 5:57:02 AM", _ 
                          "9/5/2012 8:57:02 AM","9/3/2011 4:57:02 AM")
       '-- sorted array
       outputArray = sortRange(inputArray)

          upperB = UBound(iArray, 1) '-- for 1D array you may also use UBound(iArray)
          If (Err.Number <> 0) Then '-- if there's an error, it's erro code is > 0
            MsgBox "Dates sorted, not empty"
          End If
    End Sub

    '-- dump into sheet and sort in the sheet and dump back into the array
    Function sortRange(ByVal iArray As Variant) As Variant
       Dim rngSort as Range
       Dim i As Long

       Set rngSort = WorkSheets(1).Range("B2")
       i = Ubound(iArray,1)

       With rngSort.Resize(i)
          .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(iArray)
          .Sort rngSort, xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
          sortRange = .Value              
       End With
    End Function
```

---

In terms of to-from sheet to code traffic can slow down your performance when you are handling large amount of data.

*And please do know that when someone in SO who has credibility answers (E.g. Ekkehard's answer) you gotta pay some attention. They don't say it for no proper reason.*

Comment: @TukaiRakshit if this is working, please mark - so the system is updated and we all know that another 1 out of your full list of scripting questions are solved ;)

Comment: `i = Ubound(iArray,1)` and `Ubound(outputArray) <> -1` what those statement stands for?

Comment: The routine might return nothing sometimes - means an empty array. So calling UBound() on it causes error #9 "Subscript out of
range" you can detect the error to determine sorted array is empty.

Comment: `iArray` is an 1D array then why `Ubound(iArray,1)` instead of `Ubound(iArray)`?

Comment: Both the same. You may use either if 1D

Comment: can you also help me in the merged rows post of mine!! please @bon :-)

Comment: Merge rows? Which post is that? can you show me the post? There are too many of yours.. BTW is everything clear on this one? Becaue you tick the answer. But **WE WANT TO MAKE SURE YOU GOT THE LOGIC ONCE FOR ALL FOR EACH OF YOUR QUESTIONS**

Comment: This is the post i am requesting you to help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947199/merge-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-depending-on-conditions-using-vbscript#comment19273024_13947199

Answer (score 1):

No, because you have to check the elements upto/until the first counter example (which could be the last one).

Comment: Please suggest something more advanced techniquue.