# Calling .VBS files automatically

Tags: vbscript

I have 4 .vbs files, say, A.VbS,B.VBS,C.VBS,D.VBS. I want to call them in the below order:

```
        (1)A.VBS
        (2)B.VBS
        (3)C.VBS
        (4)D.VBS
```

When the first one is done, the second one should start automatically, and so on.

Can you help me to do such tasks?

**EDIT:**

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    Dim FSO : set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Dim Path

    REM oShell.run "ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs", 1, True
    REM oShell.run "Parent_Child_Merge_final.vbs", 1, True
    REM oShell.run "Baddata.vbs", 1, True
    REM oShell.run "CycleTime.vbs", 1, True
    msgBox(oShell.CurrentDirectory)
    MsgBox(FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder )
    Path=FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder

    oShell.run Path\ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs, 1, True
    oShell.run Path\Parent_Child_Merge_final.vbs, 1, True
    oShell.run Path\Baddata.vbs, 1, True
    oShell.run Path\CycleTime.vbs, 1, True
```

I get the following error:

> Variable is undefined : "arentChildLinkFinal.vbs"

What is the fix for this?

Comment: For your edited part you need to put quotes around the name, such as "Path\ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs". Sorry, I see path is a variable. Check my updated answer with the second example then you won't need to include the path, and it can just be "ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs".

Comment: @PeterJ Excellent concept you have provided me today!! I just gave you `+1`. And I think My post also get some more `+1` to bring such research in `StackOverflow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to launch from another VBS file you can use the following if the working directory is the same as the other scripts, or otherwise include the full path:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "A.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "B.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "C.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "D.VBS", 1, True
```

As an alternative you can also expand the code to set the current directory to the folder that contains the script:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Dim FSO : Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oShell.CurrentDirectory = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder
oShell.run "A.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "B.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "C.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "D.VBS", 1, True
```

For the meaning of the parameters and other information see here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx

Comment: May I have some help for the post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895587/sorting-order-check-using-vbscript#comment19153813_13895587

Comment: Yes that's right, although I seem to recall the default start path can vary a bit either by Windows versions or how it's launched, so if you run into any file not found problems try using the full path. I often do similar thinks from a Windows task event, and that lets you set the default path to the location of the script.

Comment: Okay! I am now starting my scripts.But it could be better if in run time we can catch the file path into a variable and then adding it to the .vbs file. Is it possible?

Comment: It's oShell.CurrentDirectory you'll need, take a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156586.aspx

Comment: I am getting an error saying that `The system couldn't find the specified path`

Comment: For finding the location of the script, so you can set the default directory automatically take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2006/02/25/539226.aspx. But it's probably worth manually setting it first just to make sure it's not something else. So you probably want FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder.

Comment: I tried `MsgBox(FSO.GetFile(oShell."ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs").ParentFolder)` not working,throwing an error!

Comment: I forgot you'll need the set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") from that same page. And you don't need the script name, so just use msgbox FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder